# how can i apply << operator and ++ operator on character pointer IN C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I want to apply `<<` shifting operator on character pointer and want to increase value of this at some position.

For example: `char *p;`

In `*p`, i want to apply left shifting on some specific position `*(p+i) << 1` and `++` increment operator on specific position like `*(p+i)++`

Comment: what is the question? You show how it's done. Also, avoid Caesar Cyphers if that is what you're doing. They're pretty useless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand what you want to do, but if you want to do:

```
*(p+i) = *(p+i) << 1;
*(p+i) = *(p+i) + 1; //++
```

You can rewrite them as:

```
*(p+i) <<= 1;
*(p+i) += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your doing poor-mans obfuscation (instead of say, encryption)

```
for (char* it=strptr; *it; it++)
{
    *it <<= 1;
    (*it)++;
}
```

<sub>(assuming null-terminated string in strptr)</sub>

Note that if this is an encoding scheme, information is lost (nonreversable) if the high bit of the char is used (so only 7bit ascii is supported) and the 127 input value will need special attention when decodeing.

if you insist you could do `*it = 1 + (*it) << 1;`. However you cannot legally combine it with `it++` because it would invoke undefined behaviour as per the C++/C standard